# Pandas condition backfill in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
Name    Date    Condition   Status
A   17-12-2021      
A   18-12-2022      
A   19-12-2023      
A   20-12-2023  0   Attack
A   21-12-2023      
A   22-12-2024      
B   17-12-2021      
B   18-12-2022      
B   19-12-2023      
B   20-12-2023  2   Sprain
B   21-12-2023      
B   22-12-2024      
C   18-12-2022      
C   19-12-2023      
C   20-12-2023  1   Nausea
C   21-12-2023      
C   22-12-2024
```

Modeling assumption is the status starts before actual showing the effect so what to backfill based on Condition using for map: dict_map = {0:2, 1:1, 2:2, 3:2, 4:2}... i.e if condition is 0, need to backfill by 2, where as if condition is 1 need to backfill by 1.

Ideal output is below.  But, when I do bfill it fills all the way through. Anyway to condition bfill()?:

```
Name    Date    Condition   Status
A   17-12-2021      
A   18-12-2022      Attack
A   19-12-2023      Attack
A   20-12-2023  0   Attack
A   21-12-2023      
A   22-12-2024      
B   17-12-2021      
B   18-12-2022      Sprain
B   19-12-2023      Sprain
B   20-12-2023  2   Sprain
B   21-12-2023      
B   22-12-2024      
C   18-12-2022      
C   19-12-2023      Nausea
C   20-12-2023  1   Nausea
C   21-12-2023      
C   22-12-2024
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create helper column `new` by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for swap order, then create mask by helper groups by compare non missing values with cumulative sum and compare counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with forward filling missing values (because swapped order). Last back filling missing values and set `NaN`s in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df1 = df.assign(new=df['Condition'].map(dict_map)).iloc[::-1]

m = df1.groupby(df1['new'].notna().cumsum()).cumcount().le(df1['new'].ffill()).iloc[::-1]
    
df['Status'] = df['Status'].bfill().where(m)
print (df)
   Name        Date  Condition  Status
0     A  17-12-2021        NaN     NaN
1     A  18-12-2022        NaN  Attack
2     A  19-12-2023        NaN  Attack
3     A  20-12-2023        0.0  Attack
4     A  21-12-2023        NaN     NaN
5     A  22-12-2024        NaN     NaN
6     B  17-12-2021        NaN     NaN
7     B  18-12-2022        NaN  Sprain
8     B  19-12-2023        NaN  Sprain
9     B  20-12-2023        2.0  Sprain
10    B  21-12-2023        NaN     NaN
11    B  22-12-2024        NaN     NaN
12    C  18-12-2022        NaN     NaN
13    C  19-12-2023        NaN  Nausea
14    C  20-12-2023        1.0  Nausea
15    C  21-12-2023        NaN     NaN
16    C  22-12-2024        NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compute a mask, using a reversed [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and comparing to the [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html) "Condition" after mapping the values from the dictionary with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html). Use this mask with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) to keep only the backfilled Status within the desired limit:

```
dict_map = {0:2, 1:1, 2:2, 3:2, 4:2}

mask = (df[::-1].groupby(df.loc[::-1, 'Condition'].notna().cumsum())
        .cumcount()
        .le(df['Condition'].map(dict_map).bfill())
       )

df['Status'] = df['Status'].bfill().where(mask)
```

Output:

```
   Name        Date  Condition  Status
0     A  17-12-2021        NaN     NaN
1     A  18-12-2022        NaN  Attack
2     A  19-12-2023        NaN  Attack
3     A  20-12-2023        0.0  Attack
4     A  21-12-2023        NaN     NaN
5     A  22-12-2024        NaN     NaN
6     B  17-12-2021        NaN     NaN
7     B  18-12-2022        NaN  Sprain
8     B  19-12-2023        NaN  Sprain
9     B  20-12-2023        2.0  Sprain
10    B  21-12-2023        NaN     NaN
11    B  22-12-2024        NaN     NaN
12    C  18-12-2022        NaN     NaN
13    C  19-12-2023        NaN  Nausea
14    C  20-12-2023        1.0  Nausea
15    C  21-12-2023        NaN     NaN
16    C  22-12-2024        NaN     NaN
```

Intermediates:

```
   Name        Date  Condition  Status  cumsum/group  cumcount  condition_bfill   mask status_bfill
0     A  17-12-2021        NaN     NaN             3         3              2.0  False          NaN
1     A  18-12-2022        NaN    None             3         2              2.0   True       Attack
2     A  19-12-2023        NaN    None             3         1              2.0   True       Attack
3     A  20-12-2023        0.0  Attack             3         0              2.0   True       Attack
4     A  21-12-2023        NaN    None             2         5              2.0  False          NaN
5     A  22-12-2024        NaN    None             2         4              2.0  False          NaN
6     B  17-12-2021        NaN    None             2         3              2.0  False          NaN
7     B  18-12-2022        NaN    None             2         2              2.0   True       Sprain
8     B  19-12-2023        NaN    None             2         1              2.0   True       Sprain
9     B  20-12-2023        2.0  Sprain             2         0              2.0   True       Sprain
10    B  21-12-2023        NaN    None             1         4              1.0  False          NaN
11    B  22-12-2024        NaN    None             1         3              1.0  False          NaN
12    C  18-12-2022        NaN    None             1         2              1.0  False          NaN
13    C  19-12-2023        NaN    None             1         1              1.0   True       Nausea
14    C  20-12-2023        1.0  Nausea             1         0              1.0   True       Nausea
15    C  21-12-2023        NaN    None             0         1              NaN  False          NaN
16    C  22-12-2024        NaN    None             0         0              NaN  False          NaN
```

Answer (score -1):

Another possible solution:

```
dict_map = {0:2, 1:1, 2:2, 3:2, 4:2}

df.Status = df.groupby('Name', sort=False).apply(lambda x: x.Status.bfill(
    limit=dict_map[x['Condition'].max()])).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   Name        Date  Condition  Status
0     A  17-12-2021       <NA>     NaN
1     A  18-12-2022       <NA>  Attack
2     A  19-12-2023       <NA>  Attack
3     A  20-12-2023          0  Attack
4     A  21-12-2023       <NA>     NaN
5     A  22-12-2024       <NA>     NaN
6     B  17-12-2021       <NA>     NaN
7     B  18-12-2022       <NA>  Sprain
8     B  19-12-2023       <NA>  Sprain
9     B  20-12-2023          2  Sprain
10    B  21-12-2023       <NA>     NaN
11    B  22-12-2024       <NA>     NaN
12    C  18-12-2022       <NA>     NaN
13    C  19-12-2023       <NA>  Nausea
14    C  20-12-2023          1  Nausea
15    C  21-12-2023       <NA>     NaN
16    C  22-12-2024       <NA>     NaN
```